# in chrome just typing id of element automatically selects it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So if i have element with id asd. And i go write asd in console it will get selected. And if i write asd.addEvent...etc in script file it will work. I didn't use getElementById(.. or anything. I am confused since when did it start happening. And is it only chrome specific thing. Or Firefox and other browsers have it too. Then Why even type `documentGetElementById()`... I tried incognito mode and it worked there too. So it's not some plugins messing up.

Summary: I type id and element is selected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: i think yea thats it, good to know i wasn't going crazy.. :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out this appears to be a duplicate of [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

> Stick to document.getElementById, which is more widely-supported and less ambiguous. You can write a trivial wrapper function with a shorter name if you don't like the typing.

The short and simple answer is that compatibility is king: When you publish code for the public web with its hundreds of browser variants, taking shortcuts which potentially exclude some of your audience is a bad idea.